# pdo could not find driver with php command

Tags: php, pdo

i want run php file with php command in crontab but i have 2 problem.

1. i used pdo for connecting to database in my php file , but when i run this file with php command , i get this error :

> ```
> could not find driver
> ```

but when i run this file with browser , i dont get this error.

2. i created a text file to append crone tab lines to it , and i used this code to execute:

> exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');

but this does not work.

Comment: Apache and CLI PHP use two different php.ini files. Likely some module isn't being loaded in the CLI version.

Comment: The `cli` and embeded interpreter can use different `php.ini` files. Make sure you have PDO/mysql set up in the one that `cli` uses. Also make sure that the php invoked by the cli is the one you expect - its possible you have multiple versions on your system.

Comment: You can use `php --ini` to see the loaded config file